# Applying alternate flake8 rules to a subset of files

Tags: python, tox, flake8

I have a project where I'm using tox for testing, which runs flake8 tests.  I'd like to apply a different flake8 configuration to my tests directory from everything else; I'd like to ignore E402 on my tests because I'm messing with `sys.path` before importing the module to be tested.

The flake8 config syntax only lets you apply one configuration to files matched by include/exclude, so I've added `./tests/.flake8` to add a configuration that applies only to those files.

**./tox.ini**

```
[tox]
envlist = lint, py27, py36

[testenv]
commands =
    coverage run --source=myModule -a setup.py test

[testenv:lint]
basepython = python3
ignore_errors = True
deps =
    -r{toxinidir}/requirements_test.txt
commands =
    flake8
    pylint myModule
    pydocstyle myModule tests

[flake8]
count = true
statistics = True
```

**./tests/.flake8**

```
[flake8]
ignore = E402
```

With the flake8 options in my `tox.ini` file, the dotfile is ignored always.  With no options in the `tox.ini` file the dotfile is used by flake8 run from the command line, but ignored when it's run by tox.

It looks like there is no way to apply a different flake8 configuration to different sets of files under the same project.  Have I missed something in the configuration syntax that would allow me to do what I want here?

Comment: *the dotfile is used by flake8 run from the command line* How do you run `flake8`? Do you `cd tests`?

Comment: Command line and via the lint environment in tox.  And no, not cd'd into `tests`.. just from the root of the project.  The idea is to lint all the files in the project, but apply slightly different rules to `tests` from everything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of version 3.7.0 `flake8` [now includes](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/options.html#cmdoption-flake8-per-file-ignores) a flag to do what you want: `per-file-ignores`. To use it in your configuration file, do something like this:

```
[flake8]
per-file-ignores =
    tests/*: E402
```

It can also be applied on the command line by adding a flag like this to your `flake8` call:

```
--per-file-ignores=tests/*.py:E402
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to run `flake8` twice — once with a global config excluding `tests/` and the second run just in `tests/`:

```
commands =
    flake8 --exclude=tests
    cd tests && flake8
```

Comment: Not really a practical solution